# Display List entries that match user input value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I am a newbie to python 3 and am creating a collection programme and it consists of different types of items. I am having trouble at constructing lines of code to show items by category and deleting an entry. I'm currently trying to create an option where the user can input a type (for example Phone) and the list will show all list entries that have been added and stored as phone in the item_type.

I wrote this code, and the Show category & Delete item sections do not work. Can someone help me understand what is wrong with the code formulation:

```
def show_items():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:10}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", 'Date manufactured'))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:10}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
    response = input('Press [x] to go back to main menu or press [c] to view items by type ')
    if response == 'c':
        show_category()


def show_category():
    item_types = {"Computer": [], "Camera": [], "Phone": [], "Video Player": []}
    print()
    print('View items by type \nComputer | Camera | Phone | Video Player > ')
    response = input('Type> ')
    if response in item_types:
        print(item_types[response])
```

Comment: `if response == ['item_type'] in Item.py_collection_list` will never be `True`, that's one problem at least. We have no way of knowing the data-structure of `Item`, so unless you give us a better description of your actual problem / code, we cannot really help you.

Comment: I am currently working on a collector programme which has the basic functions to allow a user to Add, Show, Edit and Delete items from the collection. In the Show section, I need to create a function to allow users to view the entire list of entries previously added, and the option to allow the user to only view items which were added to the item types (such as Computer, Camera, Phone or Video Player). Therefore, the code needs to be able to pull in all entries from the list the entries are stored in, related to the input category the user types out.

Comment: I've changed the initial request and included the entire code, if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work:

```
            def show_items():
                print('View items by type \nComputer | Camera | Phone | Video Player ')
                type_selection = input('Type> ')
                print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
                for i in Item.py_collection_list:
                    if type_selection == i.item_type:
                        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to obtain with `Item.py_collection_list`.
A far easier way to solve this problem would be to use a dictionary.
Something like:

```
def show_category():
    all_items = {"Phone":["iPhone","OtherBrand0","OtherBrand1"], "Computer":["Asus","MSI","OtherBrand"]} # add {type: [list of products]}
    print()
    print('View items by type \nComputer | Camera | Phone | Video Player > ')
    response = input('Type> ')
    if response in all_items.keys():
        print(all_items[response]) # or whatever
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and helping me out. Unfortunately the code does not work, however I believe it is on my part, as I may have not explained the problem properly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a list of all entries as a dictionary with one of the keys being `"item_type"`, a simple list comprehension can do the job.

```
entries = [entry for entry in allEntries if entry["item_type"]==response]
```

This is equivalent to writing the following

```
entries = []
for entry in allEntries:
  if entry["item_type"] == response:
    matches.append(c)
```

Comment: Thank you your time in helping me out. Unfortunately the code does not work, however I think it is mainly due to my poor explanation.

Comment: You could try to explain what you are trying to achieve again :)

Comment: I've changed the initial request and included the entire code, if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your original question, your main stumbling-block was to return a categorized list of values inside of `Item.py_collection_list` based on user input.

Looking over your implementation of `Item` you don't seem to do the categorization inside of the class itself, so you will have to categorize the types yourself when you want to output the values.

I've simplified your code to show you how I would resolve the issue:

```
import random

class Item:
    py_collection_list = []

    def __init__(self, item_type, item_value):
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.item_value = item_value
        Item.py_collection_list.append(self)

    # To make it easier for us to represent the values inside of the categories.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item(item_type='{self.item_type}', item_value={self.item_value})"

    # We make this a classmethod because we want to be able to call it using the class, aswell as the instances.
    @classmethod
    def show_category(cls):
        # Here we dynamically create a dictionary that contans all the values inside of Item
        # which are sorted by their types.
        item_types = {}
        for item in Item.py_collection_list:
            item_types.setdefault(item.item_type, []).append(item)

        # Write all available categories
        print("Available Categories:")
        print(" | ".join(i for i in item_types))

        print("Please choose a category to show:")
        choice = input("> ")

        # Try to go through all the values of the dictionary and give back values.
        try:
            for item in item_types[choice.strip()]:
                print(item)

        except KeyError:
            print(f"Error: '{choice}' is not a valid category!")

# Lets create some random entries.
categories = ["Computer","Camera", "Phone", "Video Player"]
for i in range(100):
    Item(item_type=random.choice(categories), item_value=round(random.uniform(0.0, 10.0), 2))

Item.show_category()
```

In the above code, I have changed your function `show_category` into a classmethod if `Item`. That makes it so that we can call it in every program that we import `Item` into. I also created a `__repr__` of `Item` so that we can visualize each value more easily.

Here is the output of one of my trial-runs of the above code:

```
Available Categories:
Camera | Video Player | Phone | Computer
Please choose a category to show:
> Phone
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=7.3)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=2.34)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=0.39)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=0.03)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=5.03)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=6.72)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=6.15)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=3.33)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=0.12)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=0.63)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=9.2)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=2.99)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=0.06)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=9.25)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=6.5)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=5.51)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=2.47)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=4.4)
Item(item_type='Phone', item_value=3.8)
```

Because dictionaries are ordered by default since Python 3.6+, the order of the categories will be randomized because it's based on the order of first-appearance inside of the list that it's created from.